# How should you construct a SQL search condition against a column of type "DateTime" using a value containing just a Date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

My Question is,

I have a Column of type `DateTime` in SQL Table and it contains Values Like

```
2013-02-01 10:00:00.000
2013-01-27 16:00:00.000
2013-02-01 14:00:00.000
```

How can I get results with a Query if I only mention the Date in `Where` Clause like:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename
WHERE  columnName = '2013-02-01'
```

After executing this Query I want to have This Result

```
2013-02-01 10:00:00.000
2013-02-01 14:00:00.000
```

Kindly Help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is stored with times, you need to `Cast` those to just Dates.

Try this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE CAST(columnName as DATE) = '2013-02-01'
```

Depending on your SQL Server version (if it doesn't support DATE data type), you can use this:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, columnName)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, '2013-02-01'))
```

EDIT -- As others have rightfully pointed out, you lose any performance gained from table indexing on that column in the above example.  This should be what you're looking for given a single input parameter (2013-01-01 in this case):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE columnName >= CONVERT(datetime,'2013-01-01')
  AND columnName < DATEADD(dd, 1, CONVERT(datetime,'2013-01-01'))
```

Good luck.

Comment: Error : Type Date is not a defined system type.
Note I am Using SQL Server 2005

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am Using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't support the DATE data type -- see edits above

Comment: second query is also not returning results..!

Comment: It's because of the date conversions -- try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a14dc/4

Comment: @sgeddes, after you perform the datediff()'s both sides will have the same basis so no need to convert the results back to datetime before  means the where clause could be simplified to just `WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, 0, columnName ) = DATEDIFF(dd, 0, '2013-02-01')`.

Comment: @FahadHussain: If it "works" doesn't means it's a good solution. The second solution is not [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). You should look at Mikael Eriksson's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Applying functions to the column will make your query [non-sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and it will mess up your [Cardinality Estimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181034%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Use an interval instead.

```
select *
from tablename
where columnName >= '20130201' and
      columnName < '20130202'
```

Note: [The dateformat `YYYY-MM-DD` is not always interpreted the way you think in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#YYYYMMDD).

To avoid ambiguity of date interpretation use the universal date format literal 'YYYYMMDD'.

```
set language German
go
select convert(datetime, '1989-06-12'),
       convert(datetime, '19890612'),
       convert(datetime2, '1989-06-12'),
       convert(datetime2, '19890612'),
       convert(date, '1989-06-12'),
       convert(date, '19890612')
```

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: why people are forcing me to accept your answer, although your answer not completing my requirements.
Interval will not work for me as there is only one input date.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson But Your Query does not meet my Requirements

Comment: Nobody is forcing you to do anything. Do it like [this (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f735c/1) if you only want to use one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename 
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, columnname, 103) = '01/01/2013'
```